# How do I go about either finding or calculating Aluminum-Oxalate salt solubility values in aqueous medium?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, aqueous-solution, solubility

Water would contain other salts which may complicate things a bit. But finding out the Aluminum-Oxalate salts solubility values in pure water would be a good indicator already. It's for temperatures from 10-50C. Wikipedia doesn't have a page for Al-Oxalate but it has a page here: https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Aluminum_oxalate